# How to call a specific S4 method in R

Tags: r

I was working in the `mirt` package in R and noticed that I couldn't use `mirt::` or `mirt:::` to call the `coef` or `residuals` functions. From what I can tell this is a S3 to S4 difference (magic fingers & hand waving).

Which brings me to the question, how do you call a specific R function within it's package when it's coded in S4?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example demonstrating exactly what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @cdeterman `mirt:::coef()` doesn't call the unique parameters for `coef` within `mirt`. My question is simply how to do that.

Comment: Sure,  but without an example it is more difficult to verify any potential solution.  Not everyone is familiar with the `mirt` package.  What error are you receiving?  Why not just load the package and apply the functions on their respective objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
> library(mirt)
Loading required package: stats4
Loading required package: lattice
```

I see

```
> methods(coef)
 [1] coef,ANY-method                coef,DiscreteClass-method     
 [3] coef,MixedClass-method         coef,mle-method               
 [5] coef,MultipleGroupClass-method coef,SingleGroupClass-method  
 [7] coef,summary.mle-method        coef.aov*                     
 [9] coef.Arima*                    coef.default*                 
[11] coef.listof*                   coef.nls*                     
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

I guess you have an instance of one of the classes, e.g., 'DiscreteClass'. You can select the method with

```
selectMethod("coef", signature="DiscreteClass")
```

or maybe more naturally

```
selectMethod("coef", class(obj))
```

where `obj` is an instance of the object you're interested in. But you shouldn't have to call a specific method; this should be taken care of -- what's the problem you're actually experiencing.